# Cardinality of an uncountable union of countably infinite sets?

Tags: set-theory

Let $I$ be an uncountable directed set and $T = \{E_{\alpha}:\alpha \in I\}$ denote  a collection of Countably infinite sets with $E_{\alpha} \subset E_{\beta}$ whenever $\alpha \le \beta$. Also $T$ is totally ordered with respect to set incusion. What will the cardinality of $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} E_{\alpha}$ be?

Comment: Is the inclusion always strict?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer.

Comment: Take any infinite set, and consider its countable subsets under inclusion.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma - Yes.

Comment: @Andres E. Caicedo - Have modified the question.

Comment: Again, there is not enough information to answer.

Comment: I think the answer is "either $\aleph_0$ or $\aleph_1$".

Answer (score 1):

> **Lemma.** If $X$ is a family of countable sets which is well-ordered under $\subseteq$, then $|X|\leq\aleph_1$.

There are two options:

1. The cofinality of $T$ is countable. Namely, there is a countable set $T_0$, such that for any $E_\alpha\in T$ there is some $E_\beta\in T_0$ such that $E_\alpha\subseteq E_\beta$. Therefore $\bigcup T=\bigcup T_0$.
2. There is no such countable set. In that case using the above lemma the cofinality of $T$ must be $\aleph_1$. Therefore, $\bigcup T$ is equivalent to the union of $\aleph_1$ countable sets, so it must have cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers.

Comment: If the assumption of "countably infinite" from the question is replaced by "infinite sets of cardinality at most some cardinality $\kappa$. Is there a version of the lemma that you had stated, for this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course. Replace $\aleph_0$ (or countable) by $\kappa$ (or $\leq\kappa$), consequently $\aleph_1$ becomes $\kappa^+$.

Comment: Sorry, but what is $\kappa^+$?

Comment: The successor cardinal of $\kappa$.